# How to create custom method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I'm currently trying to use a custom method in Rails and I do not know how to do so. Apart from the default methods in the controller, I wanted to add the following:

```
  def cancel
    @newsletter = Newsletter.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|

  #SendGrid Newsletter API - Delete Newsletter Schedule
  SendGrid.delete_schedule(@newsletter.name)

  @newsletter.status = "CANCELLED"

  @newsletter.save

  format.html { redirect_to newsletters_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

end

The method is just like the default :destroy method but it doesn't actually destroys the object.

In my view, I had the following:

```
<% @newsletters.each do |newsletter| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= newsletter.identity %></td>
    <td><%= newsletter.name %></td>
    <td><%= newsletter.recipients %></td>
    <td><%= newsletter.subject %></td>
    <td><%= newsletter.html %></td>
    <td><%= newsletter.text %></td>
    <td><%= newsletter.schedule %></td>
    <td><%= newsletter.status %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', newsletter %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_newsletter_path(newsletter) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', newsletter, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <td><% if newsletter.status == "SCHEDULED" %><%= link_to 'Cancel', newsletter, method: :cancel, data: { confirm: 'Cancel Schedule?' }%><% end %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I got the error: No route matches [POST] "***_****newsletter url***__**"

When I rake routes, there isn't any route for the error above. May I know how to add the route and why is the route needed?

---

**UPDATE** 
Currently, I still have the no route matches error. Below are all my files related to the 'Cancel' method:

#### routes.rb

```
  resources :newsletters do
    match '/cancel/:id' => 'newsletters#cancel', :as => :cancel
  end
```

#### newsletters_controller.rb

def cancel
    @newsletter = Newsletter.find(params[:id])

```
respond_to do |format|

#SendGrid Newsletter API - Delete Newsletter Schedule
  SendGrid.delete_schedule(@newsletter.name)

  @newsletter.status = "CANCELLED"

  @newsletter.save

  format.html { redirect_to newsletters_path(@newsletter) }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

#### newsletters/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', newsletter_cancel_path(newsletter) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mistaking the `method:` argument in the `link_to` as corresponding to the method in the controller.  Actually it is referring to the RESTful HTTP verb i.e. :post, :delete and :put.  So you don't pass the controller action through this way.

Instead you can pass in :controller and :action arguments...

Better still create a route in routes.rb and use the path that rails generates.

```
match "/cancel/:id", to: "controller#cancel", as: :cancel
```

and then the link_to would be something like:

```
link_to 'Cancel', cancel_path(newsletter)
```

**Update:**
The error you're getting is with the redirect_to in your cancel method (in the controller).  Change the newsletters_url to `newsletter_path(@newsletter)` instead.

If you want to redirect back to the show page for a single newsletter, then you need to do the above (where you pass in the @newsletter parameter), if you want it to go back to the newsletters index page then it'll be `newsletters_path`.

You can check the existence of the routes by typing `rake routes` in your terminal.  You'll see all the route names there.

Do you still get an error after changing to `redirect_to newsletter_path(@newsletter)`?

**The thing that doesn't quite strike true** is that you're getting a no POST route defined - which usually points to a malformed `form_for`.  Examine your newsletter related forms especially any where you don't do the regular `form_for @newsletter do |f|`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That made a lot of sense. Really understood what the codes mean now! However, I'm still unable to get the codes working. I still got the same error of no route matches. :( Is there anything else I need to edit?

Comment: Do you get the error when trying to see the view page?  Or when you click on the cancel link?  Also I presume in addition to the cancel route you've set up, you also have a resource for newsletter in your routes.rb file.  Please post your amended code.

Comment: I got the error when clicking on the cancel link.

Here's the newsletter resource:
  resources :newsletters do
    match "/cancel/:id", to: "newsletters#cancel", as: :cancel
  end

Comment: Please check my updated answer.  Fix the params for redirect_to in your controller.

Comment: Please refer to my updated qn at the top to see if there's any problems with my codes :/

Answer (score 2):

You should have a line like this in your `config/routes.rb` file

```
resources :newsletters
```

You'll want to change it to this

```
resources :newsletters do
  member do
    put 'cancel'
  end
end
```

You'll want to take a look at the routing guide that Иван Бишевац posted. You'll also want to understand basic restful routing and how Rails handles GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

Comment: I did that but it shows the same error:X Do I need to change anything else apart from the routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete explanation about routing:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html